# Grouping sf object by one variable using R

Tags: r, sf, network

I have this code which allow me to calculate the distance of sfc_POINT along a sfc_LINESTRING

```
library(dplyr)
library(units)
library(sf)
library(sfnetworks)

distances <- net %>% group_by(I) %>%  
  activate("edges") %>% 
  mutate(length = set_units(edge_length(),m)) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_drop_geometry
```

It gives the cumulate distance for all points, but I would like to group the distance calculation by 'I' (cumulate the distance among I = 1 and I = 2). Which does not seem to work despite the use of the function `group_by()`.

the 'net' sfc object come from `sfnetworks::st_network_bend()` of points from the object `Test` and the network `Riv`

```
test <- structure(list(N = c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20), I = c("1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(163339.007569445, 86057.5225402927), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163343.429912257, 86059.4221890382
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163343.159782333, 
    86058.8714383775), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163347.471221711, 
    86061.2705156468), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163360.754470705, 
    86055.9812574657), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163338.188246187, 
    86057.2636421723), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163358.405840557, 
    86056.243204223), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163342.946671779, 
    86059.1878993558), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163352.392959929, 
    86057.6097731385), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(163336.815430932, 
    86052.9286830882), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 163336.815430932, 
ymin = 86052.9286830882, xmax = 163360.754470705, ymax = 86061.2705156468
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:31370", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    lon = c(`1` = 163339.007569445, `2` = 163343.429912257, `3` = 163343.159782333, 
    `4` = 163347.471221711, `5` = 163360.754470705, `6` = 163338.188246187, 
    `7` = 163358.405840557, `8` = 163342.946671779, `9` = 163352.392959929, 
    `10` = 163336.815430932), lat = c(`1` = 86057.5225402927, 
    `2` = 86059.4221890382, `3` = 86058.8714383775, `4` = 86061.2705156468, 
    `5` = 86055.9812574657, `6` = 86057.2636421723, `7` = 86056.243204223, 
    `8` = 86059.1878993558, `9` = 86057.6097731385, `10` = 86052.9286830882
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(N = NA_integer_, 
I = NA_integer_, lon = NA_integer_, lat = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Riv <- structure(list(id = 1, Type = NA_character_, geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(163293.837499969, 163298.070833307, 163303.18611109, 
    163310.77083332, 163317.38541666, 163323.294444444, 163332.290277786, 
    163339.081250015, 163345.607638911, 163350.105555582, 163354.691666698, 
    163359.277777814, 163362.981944484, 163366.774305599, 163371.007638937, 
    163373.477083384, 163416.868750095, 163424.629861214, 163427.716666772, 
    163443.238889011, 163457.61458347, 163468.021527925, 163473.136805708, 
    163479.839583492, 163489.71736128, 163500.918055736, 163514.235416861, 
    163542.193055778, 163550.659722453, 163557.450694683, 163561.772222465, 
    163570.503472474, 163574.031250255, 163573.590278032, 163570.679861363, 
    163566.181944692, 163560.802083575, 163561.419444687, 163563.359722466, 
    163568.29861136, 163569.533333584, 163573.325694699, 163575.706944701, 
    163583.820833598, 163593.610416942, 163595.9034725, 163599.960416948, 
    163605.957639177, 163622.802778083, 163638.148611432, 163646.174305884, 
    163659.668055898, 163670.251389242, 163690.536111485, 86050.9986111142, 
    86054.438194451, 86056.4666666753, 86053.4680555611, 86049.4111111126, 
    86048.5291666672, 86049.9402777798, 86053.6444444502, 86059.377083345, 
    86060.9645833466, 86059.9944444567, 86056.907638898, 86054.438194451, 
    86054.1736111174, 86055.761111119, 86056.9958333425, 86057.2604166761, 
    86059.553472234, 86060.6118055684, 86060.1708333457, 86064.3159722389, 
    86071.4597222462, 86078.1625000308, 86087.2465278178, 86090.6861111547, 
    86092.0972222672, 86092.5381944899, 86094.037500047, 86097.2125000502, 
    86099.5937500526, 86104.444444502, 86116.8798611814, 86127.375000081, 
    86133.9013889765, 86141.3979167619, 86146.7777778785, 86151.7166667725, 
    86155.9500001101, 86165.3868056753, 86181.7909723587, 86187.7000001425, 
    86196.8722223741, 86201.2819446008, 86203.8395834923, 86203.8395834923, 
    86200.4000001555, 86195.372916817, 86192.5506945919, 86189.9930557004, 
    86191.2277779239, 86193.4326390372, 86194.1381945935, 86193.7854168154, 
    86186.5534723636), dim = c(54L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"BD72\",\n        DATUM[\"Reseau National Belge 1972\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"International 1924\",6378388,297,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4313]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Belgian Lambert 72\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",90,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",4.36748666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",51.1666672333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",49.8333339,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",150000.013,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",5400088.438,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Belgium - onshore.\"],\n        BBOX[49.5,2.5,51.51,6.4]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",31370]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 163293.837499969, 
ymin = 86048.5291666672, xmax = 163690.536111485, ymax = 86203.8395834923
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
Type = NA_integer_), class = "factor", levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

```
net <- net %>% filter(., !is.na(I)) #To keep only points from test
net <- as_sfnetwork(Riv) |> 
  st_network_blend(test)
```

Comment: Which packages are you using here? I can guess some are `dplyr` but I'm not sure where things like `st_network_blend` and other network functions come from. [scans CRAN] is it `sfnetworks`?

Comment: @Spacedman I have added the packages associated with this code.

Comment: There's not much effect on grouping as tidygraph `activate()` first ungroups. `I` being a node attribute, how would grouping by `I` work or what is the expected output and the context here?  
A quick plot of nodes, coloured by `I`, and edges with lengths - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMru6.png . For example, group `I == 2` (green), are you after a single value of `5.31` (only edge still remaining when removing `I == 1` nodes and related edges. Or distance along the line from the first node in group to the last? Or list of 3 lengths, sections between 4 `I == 1` lengths? Or something else?